# Open Listview "Subitems"

Tags: android, listview

I would like to populate my listview with subitems.

My target is, when someone clicks at a listview row, this listview shows a subitem, just like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QrAV.png)

I shouldn't call this a subitem, but I found that this was the best way to describe what I'm trying to do.

I'm not using libraries to do that, I just included in my listview rows an layout, and I'm trying to hide and show it when someone clicks on it.

My Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="400sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2sp"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200sp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3">
</RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_subitem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/subitem"
        android:layout_height="200sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I built a simple adapter, and I'm trying to implement there my ideas, but is not working, because nothing happens

```
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
                        final ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        layout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        subitem = v.findViewById(R.id.subitem);

        if (flag){

        subitem.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        layout.getLayoutParams().height = 200;

       }

         v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                subitem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layout.getLayoutParams().height = 400;
                flag = false;

            }
        });

        return v;

}
```

Can you guys help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you try to use Expandable List?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: I never heard about, I will use it thank you